# Comment mieux tourner « Tu aurais vécu l’enfer si tu avais étudié dans une université où les exposés oraux sont mis en avant. »?

Tags: syntaxe, constructions, formulation

Je suis conscient que le français est une langue complexe, qu’il existe plusieurs façons de formuler une phrase. Je cherche à m’exprimer le plus simplement possible sans fioritures d’une part et d’une manière qui tende vers le bon usage. Bref je tiens à être compris de tous. Si vous pensez que la phrase doit être entièrement repensée, faites-le-moi savoir et n’hésitez pas à me faire part de vos suggestions. Je vous souhaite une bonne journée.

La formulation « mettre en avant » me laisse hésitant. D’autre part j’hésite entre l’emploi de «dans une université » et « à une université »

Aussi, si jamais la phrase n’a pas à être entièrement repensée, pensez-vous qu’il serait préférable d’écrire «...une université qui met en avant les exposés oraux » plutôt que « ... université où les exposés oraux sont mis en avant ».

Merci à tous.

Answer (score 1):

- "Mettre en avant" est en effet une tournure un peu lourde et maladroite. Je suggèrerais "accorder de l'importance" ou bien "insister sur".
- On dit le plus souvent "étudier dans une université" mais "étudier à l'université" (selon l'article utilisé).

Donc je vous suggèrerais de reformuler votre phrase comme ceci:

> "Tu aurais vécu l'enfer si tu avais étudié dans une université qui accorde de l'importance aux exposés oraux."

Ou bien:

> "Tu aurais vécu l'enfer si tu avais étudié dans une université qui accorde beaucoup d'importance aux exposés oraux."

Ou bien encore:

> "Tu aurais vécu l'enfer si tu avais étudié dans une université qui insiste sur les exposés oraux."

Comment: l'adjectif "primordial" ("les oraux sont primordiaux") me semble adéquat, bien que d'un registre un peu soutenu.